# While with multiple conditions

Tags: c, conditional-statements

This is my code.The user enters a string and if the input is 1,2 or * it displays error.The problem is that the condition is satisfied for all the numbers of which the first digits are 1,2 amd 3.(11,12,22...).I used also strlen and sizeof function to count the digits and create a condition that works but when i printed strlen the output was 1 for every number.

I don't understand if the problem is my multiple conditions or the use of scanf

*Here is my code*

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main (void)
{
    char choice;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        scanf("%s", &choice);
        while(choice !='1' &&  choice !='2' && choice !='*' )
        {
            printf("error");
            scanf("%s",&choice);
        }

    }while (choice !='0');
    return 0;
    }
```

I would be very thankful for any help. I am quite new in programming, so forgive me if the question is stupid.

Comment: `%s` is a format specifier for a null-terminated string, not `char`.

Comment: `char choice;` -> `scanf("%c", &choice);` and `int choice;` -> `scanf("%d",&choice);`.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.   2) when requesting a single char from the user, use " %c"  The leading space is so any leading 'white space' (newline, tab, space) is consumed.

Comment: When requesting anything from the user, always prompt the user, so they know what the program is expecting them to do.

Comment: what happens if the user enters 'a' or '9' etc?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `fgets` to obtain input, then parse with `sscanf`. Using `int choice` allows you to distinguish between 1 and 11...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void) {
    char input[99] = "";
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "Enter 0 to quit\n");
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            if ( 1 == sscanf ( input, "%d", &choice)) {
                if ( choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3) {
                    printf ( "error\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf ( "you entered %d\n", choice);
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( 0 == strcmp ( input, "*\n")) {
                    printf ( "error\n");
                }
                //sscanf could not parse an int
                choice = -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;// fgets failed
        }
    } while ( choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose you the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
        char choice[201];

        do
        {
                scanf("%200s", choice);
                if (strcmp(choice, "1") == 0 ||
                                strcmp(choice, "2") == 0 ||
                                strcmp(choice, "3") == 0)
                        printf("error");
        } while (strcmp(choice, "0") != 0);

        return 0;
}
```

`%s` waits for a `char *` argument, your `&choice` was right, but scanf will write a whole string at the address pointed to, which can (will) contain more than one char. By giving the address of a char variable, you provided it with the room for only one char.

You can't compare strings with a comparison operator, you have to use, for example, the `strcmp` function, which returns 0 if it's two argument do match and non-zero otherwise.

If I properly understood your intent, there is no need for two nested while loop. The two `scanf` calls aren't needed either.

The `200` in the `%200s` scanf format string, limits the number of chars which will be written in the array you have provided the address of.
This array is of size `201` to account for the extra '\0' byte, terminating C strings.

To write properly this code, one should test the return of scanf, to check if something has been parsed with success.
Please refer to the man page of scanf to see how to check if the parsing went successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `choice` as a `char` object - it's only large enough to store a single character value.  If you're entering a string like `"123"` on input, only the leading `'1'` is stored to `choice` and the remaining input is written to memory immediately following `choice`, which *may* cause a runtime error if you clobber anything important.

If you want to read and store the input as a *string* of characters, then you need to declare `choice` as an *array* of `char`, sized to hold *at least* one more character than the maximum input size - IOW, if you expect the maximum string to be 3 characters long, then `choice` must be declared as `char choice[4];`.

If you want to read and store the input as an *integer*, then you must declare choice as `int` instead of `char`, and you need to use the `%d` conversion specifier instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. only calls `scanf()` once per each outer loop
3. prompts the user for the desired input

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main (void)
{
    char choice;

    do
    {
        printf( "enter 0:" );
        if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &choice) )
        {
            perror( "scanf failed" );  // to stderr:
                                       // enclosed text + reason OS thinks it failed
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );      // once failed, it will continue to fail
                                       // so exit program with error indication
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        // what about other user inputs?
        if(choice !='1' &&  choice !='2' && choice !='*' )
        {
            printf("error\n");         // trailing '\n'
                                       // so immediately displayed on terminal
                                       // note: should use: 'fprintf( stderr, ... )'
                                       // because error messages should 
                                       // be output to 'stderr', not 'stdout'
        }
    } while (choice !='0');

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```